# Name for phrases that sound the same but have different meanings?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, ambiguity, sounds

Is there a special name for two phrases that have the same sound, but mean different things from each other? For example

> Wishing well

Could be used in either the context of "I wish you well," or that of "I threw a coin a coin into the well and made a wish."

It would be something like homophones but with phrases. I googled "Homophone Phrases" thinking that would be the appropriate terminology, but only found one blog that agreed with me.

Does anyone know whether there exists specific terminology for this kind of phrase or I should just stick with "Homophone Phrase?"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> **HOMOGRAPHS** are words that are spelled the same but have different meanings. **Heteronyms** are a type of homograph that are also spelled the same and have different meanings, but sound different.

[source](http://www.magickeys.com/books/riddles/words.html)

Comment: I edited your answer to give an actual (relevant) quotation from the source you provided. Please do not provide link-only answers, as they would become meaningless if the link ever becomes unreachable.

Comment: I'm kind of confused... Your answer says Heteronyms are pronounced the same, but your citation says they are pronounced differently. Which one is correct? Edit: Just looked it up, apparently the correct definition is the citation. Thanks, Google dictionary entries!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are called "phrase rhymes" or "double rhymes"

What you are looking for are called "phrase rhymes" or "double rhymes". There are a tone of them but they are not complete rhymes or proper homophones. They are "similar" and you could get away with it -- they are often found inside the complex rhyme patters of Rap songs. 
https://double-rhyme.com/?hl=en-us&s=irish

I wish

But also called Mosaic Rhymes -- rhymes with more than one word.
https://wikirhymer.com/words/irish

buy fish
why rich

Hope that helps.

***EDIT:***

I also found Holorimes 
Holorhyme is a form of rhyme where two very similar sequence of sounds can form phrases composed of slightly or completely different words and with different meanings. For example, in some British English dialects, the following lines are pronounced identically:

"In Ayrshire hill areas, a cruise, eh, lass?"
"Inertia, hilarious, accrues, hélas!"
—Miles Kington, "A Lowlands Holiday Ends in Enjoyable Inactivity".

And I also realized that what they really are is "Puns"

ICBM
Icy BM

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was pretty cool to look into. But the question is more about phrases that are spelled exactly the same.